# Lombok won't generate getter methods for variables when annotation is in class level

Tags: java, lombok

I'm quite confused as to why the annotation won't create getter methods for the variables if the annotation is at class level

```
@Getter
public class Config {

    private static final String TEST = "";
}
```

But creates the getters if annotation is at the variable level.

```
public class Config {
    @Getter
    private static final String TEST = "";
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please read the documentation in future. "*You can also put a `@Getter` and/or `@Setter` annotation on a class. In that case, it's as if you annotate **all the non-static fields** in that class with the annotation.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Class` level `Getter` annotation doesn't work with `Static` fields. Check the Lombok documentation [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter). Please refer to the screenshot below --

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as [the documentation says](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter):

> You can annotate a class with a @Getter or @Setter annotation. Doing so is equivalent to annotating all non-static fields in that class with that annotation. @Getter/@Setter annotations on fields take precedence over the ones on classes.

The problem you're seeing is because the field you're having problems with is `static`.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up this point. I wanted to understand the class level and field level precedence for @ Getter and @ Setter